# Change Display to None in CSS

Tags: css

I use shortcode to embed an HTML world map on one of my web pages.  Right below the world map is a third party link for which I want to set the display value to "none", however since I have no CSS skills or web dev background I am having difficulty writing the custom CSS for this.  I've played around with containers and specific page ID's, but no luck. The page is www.sheerheroine.com/map.  Can anyone steer me in the right direction on how to write the code please? When I inspect the page I can see which container the link is in, however when I use this container the entire map is removed. Thanks!

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the tme to read this: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).  Also take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a good question

Comment: Did you buy it? Otherwise it's not legal to remove it..

Comment: This link has inline css rule for display with `!important` so there is no chance to hide it by just add `display: none`. Some crazy solution is to place some white div over this link to hide it xD As Goombah said it is not legal ;)

Answer (score -1):

The `!important` declaration makes the display CSS impossible to override.  The following javascript would remove the element you wish to not display -- `document.getElementsByClassName('fm-map-container')[0].childNodes[3].remove();`.  Try it in the developer's console.  For it to work on the page, you would need to delay the execution until the element exists though.  As others suggest, it would seemingly violate the terms of use of the lovely vector map you are using free of charge.  For a proof-of-concept, however, you may find this code enlightening.

Comment: In response to the downvote, I suppose I didn't actually answer the question.  This javascript does as the asker wishes (sets display to none, overriding the existing display CSS):  `document.getElementsByClassName('fm-map-container')[0].childNodes[3].style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score -2):

```
As the entire map con-taint is coming because of thirdparty image, better check with the that third party style code. 

Or 

in alternatively, just check the the height of the total map area. 
lets assume here total height of map image is 10px from bottom. 
and lets assume the height of that area(to which area,you don't want to show user) is 2 px from bottom.



Then create a div element, where you will put the entire map image, but follow the below stlye, where we can hide some portion of image to user

 <div style="max-width: (10 - 2)px"> here .. put your map image url..</div>
```